# split string based on words and highlighted portions with `^` sign

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that has highlighted portions with `^` sign:

```
const inputValue = 'jhon duo ^has a car^ right ^we know^ that';
```

Now how to return an array which is splited based on words and `^` highlights, so that we return this array:

```
['jhon','duo', 'has a car', 'right', 'we know', 'that']
```

Using `const input = inputValue.split('^');` to split by `^` and `const input = inputValue.split(' ');` to split by words is not working and I think we need a better idea.

How would you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `match` with a regular expression:

```js
const inputValue = 'jhon duo ^has a car^ right ^we know^ that';
const result = Array.from(inputValue.matchAll(/\^(.*?)\^|([^^\s]+)/g),
                          ([, a, b]) => a || b);
console.log(result);
```

- `\^(.*?)\^` will match a literal `^` and all characters until the next `^` (including it), and the inner part is captured in a capture group
- `([^^\s]+)` will match a series of non-white space characters that are not `^` (a "word") in a second capture group
- `|` makes the above two patterns alternatives: if the first doesn't match, the second is tried.
- The `Array.from` callback will extract only what occurs in a capture group, so excluding the `^` characters.

Comment: Thanks, I used `inputValue.match(/\^.*?\^|\S+/g).map(e => e.replaceAll('^', ''))` to remove the sign too, any better solution ?

Comment: and not working if `^` have an extra space surrounding like `const inputValue = 'jhon duo has a^ car right^ we know that';`

Comment: What is the expected result in that case?

Comment: it shouldn't be different than this one: `'jhon duo has a ^car right^ we know that'. we still highlighted that portion.

Comment: See update to the answer, but if after the first `^`  there is a space, it will be included in the match, just like other spaces that occur between both `^` .

Comment: used a map to trim the result but accepted this, thanks..

Comment: Then use the existing callback to do that: `(a || b).trim()`.

Answer (score 1):

trincot's answer is good, but here's a version that doesn't use regex and will throw an error when there are mismatched `^`:

```js
function splitHighlights (inputValue) {
  const inputSplit = inputValue.split('^');
  let highlighted = true
  const result = inputSplit.flatMap(splitVal => {
    highlighted = !highlighted
    if (splitVal == '') {
      return [];
    } else if (highlighted) {
      return splitVal.trim();
    } else {
      return splitVal.trim().split(' ')
    }
  })
  if (highlighted) {
    throw new Error(`unmatched '^' char: expected an even number of '^' characters in input`);
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(splitHighlights('^jhon duo^ has a car right ^we know^ that'));
console.log(splitHighlights('jhon duo^ has^ a car right we^ know that^'));
console.log(splitHighlights('jhon duo^ has a car^ right ^we know^ that'));
console.log(splitHighlights('jhon ^duo^ has a car^ right ^we know^ that'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `split()` but [capture the split-sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split?retiredLocale=de#splitting_with_a_regexp_to_include_parts_of_the_separator_in_the_result) to include it in the output.
For splitting you could use  [`*\^([^^]*)\^ *| +`](https://regex101.com/r/lHDtAn/1) to get trimmed items in the results.

```js
const inputValue = 'jhon duo ^has a car^ right ^we know^ that';

// filtering avoids empty items if split-sequence at start or end
let input = inputValue.split(/ *\^([^^]*)\^ *| +/).filter(Boolean);

console.log(input);
```

| regex | matches |
| --- | --- |
| `*\^` | [any amount](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of space followed by a literal caret |
| `([^^]*)` | [captures](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) *any amount* of [non](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)-carets |
| `\^ *` | literal caret followed by *any amount* of space |
| `| +` | [OR](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) split at *one or more* spaces |